# I'm new to Git... How can I start using Git on multiple projects?

Tags: git, version-control

I am new to Git, and I'm not sure on how to use it for putting multiple projects under version control. Should I simply just run `git init` in a new directory in order to create a new project to track?

Also, I'm thinking of using Bitbucket to push my code there... Or should I simply use Git locally?

Comment: gitlab is a good option if you want to do things locally.

Comment: Maybe, before to ask it's better to know what you are talking about... Search on the web, or take an introduction to git as for example https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1
Avoid to post useless questions as this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem very familiar with Git (yet); I strongly recommend that, before anything, you read the first two chapters of the [Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book). That will get you started very quickly.

> Should I simply just run `git init` in a new directory in order to create a new project to track?

You should initialize a Git repository in the root directory of each project. For instance, if all the files relevant to Project A live under `~/projectA/`, you should run

```
cd ~/projectA
git init
```

Important: (unless you know what you're doing) **do not nest project root directories**. For instance, the `projectA` directory should *not* be contained in `projectB/`.

> Also, I'm thinking of using Bitbucket to push my code there, or could I simply just use git locally as a version control?

You can use Git only locally, if you want. However, you may also want to set up, as a backup, a remote repository (one for each of your projects) on one of the hosting services (such as Bitbucket), so you can push your code to it. All that is explained in [the second chapter of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics).

Comment: Thanks for making it clear to me, I will look into that book aswell!
And yeah, I just started out using Git but I can already see it helping me alot. Last question, do I make a checkout in order to switch between diffrent projects?

Comment: No. To "switch" to some project B, you would just `cd` to the root directory of project B. Also, don't nest project root directories, e.g. don't have project A live in a subdirectory of project B's root directory.

Comment: Thanks alot! And I learn alot from the book aswell

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `git init` starts a new local project.

Yes, you can use it locally only. Just make sure you back it up somewhere.